# Probability word problem regarding discrete random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Here's a problem I can't seem to get. The problem goes as follows: A box contains 20 items of which 25% is defective. Three items are chosen one after another without replacement. Let X be the number of defective in the three selected items. a) Find the probability that the first item selected is defective. b) After selecting a defective item on the first selection, what is the probability that the second item is defective?

Answer (score 1):

So there are 5 defective items.

a) there are 5 defective out of 20 items. So P(1st item is defective) = 5/20 = 0.25

b) there are 4 defective items left and there are 19 items left. So P(2nd item is defective given the 1st item is defective) = 4/19.

Comment: Well there's a third part to this question and it asks if X is a binomial random variable, so I thought you had to use that equation.